# TypeError (can't concatenate NoneType to str)

Tags: python, typeerror

```py
def emoji_convert(massage):
    split_words = massage.split(" ")
    emoji = {
        ":)": " ",
        ":(": " ",
        ":": " ",
        ":|": " "
    }
    output = ""
    for words in split_words:
        output += emoji.get(words)
    return output


massage=(input("> "))
print(emoji_convert(massage))
```

get this type error

```py
    output += emoji.get(words)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: The error tells you that the thing on the right of `+=` is `None`, so you tried to look up a string in the dictionary that isn't there.

Comment: the `get` method of a dict returns None by default if the argument is not found in the dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest fix is to change the default when `emoji` doesn't have a match from `None` to instead an empty string:

```
output += emoji.get(words, '')
```

...or, to pass the word through unmodified (but for a leading space) when it isn't found:

```
output += emoji.get(words, ' ' + words)
```

You might also consider generating your output as a *list*, and converting that list to a string right before returning it, thus more properly mirroring the `split()` you did earlier.

```
def emoji_convert(message):
    split_words = message.split(" ")
    emoji = {
        ":)": "",
        ":(": "",
        ":":  "",
        ":|": "",
    }
    output = []
    for word in split_words:
        output.append(emoji.get(word), word)
    return ' '.join(output)

message = input("> ")
print(emoji_convert(message))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method with an element which is not in the dictionary.

From the python docs:

> **`get`** *`(key[, default])`*
> Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

If you used `emoji[word]` this would have raised a `KeyError`. Instead, `emoji.get(word)` returns the *default*, which is `None`.

So either provide a string default which can be added to the existing string, or handle invalid inputs some other way.